# People picker field in sharepoint, CommaSeparatedAccounts as domain\\user

Tags: sharepoint, peoplepicker

I have a people pickerfield in sharepoint. I expect to return its CommaSeparatedAccounts as domain\user.

But it returns CommaSeparatedAccounts' value as **"i:0#.w|domain\user"**

Find the code sample.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="spuc" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
             Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<spuc:PeopleEditor ID="PeopleEditor1" runat="server"
                   AllowEmpty="true" MultiSelect="false" SelectionSet="User"  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will give you the login name in the same format. 
But you can decode this in your code behind.

Use the following code to decode the username :

```
string userName = null;
SPClaimProviderManager mgr = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
if (mgr != null)
{
    userName = mgr.DecodeClaim(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName).Value;
}
```